# docker bridge network using docker-compose can't access VPN resources

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, vpn

Environment:

- Ubuntu 17.04
- Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
- docker-compose version 1.14.0-rc1, build c18a7ad

I'm connected to a Juniper VPN using openconnect and while docker can access the docker repo inside the VPN to download images, containers running on docker-compose can't access anything inside of it. Trying with actual IPs doesn't work either so it's not just a DNS issue.

I've tried restarting docker, but didn't work. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or fix this?

Comment: Routing problem? Any hint in the `route -n` output in a container?

Comment: Try restart docker while the vpn is connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed `dnsmasq` and configured docker to point to the `docker0` address as it's DNS provider:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "dns": ["172.17.0.1"]
}
```

This still requires me to restart `dnsmasq` whenever I connect to the VPN or to update this info whenever the `docker0` address changes, but it's definitely better than not doing anything.